# Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful while deploying app to bluemix using cf

Tags: deployment, cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, watson-conversation

0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 crashed
FAILED
Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful

TIP: use 'cf logs UP_Chatbot_pipeline --recent' for more information

Finished: FAILED

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYMf5.jpg)

Comment: See the tip to see the logs. Add the relevant log parts, details about your app and how you pushed to the question.

Comment: 2018-10-16T05:48:13.06-0400 [API/25] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web" 2018-10-16T05:50:16.20-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR designed for a production en vironment, as it will leak 2018-10-16T05:50:16.21-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Error: Argument error: usern ame and password are required unless use_unauthenticated is set This app is build on IBM conversations, using tool-chain I am trying to deploy it to bluemix using cf push

Comment: Are you following a particular tutorial or pattern you can link? Did you enter your username/password or token in the environment variables before pushing?

Comment: I have entered the username password and workspace id in environment variables.  I dont have any link to tutorial . I have previously deployed the app using same procedure and following the same now. I see some of the cloud services are deprecated and I am forced to use the available/upgraded services that I have mention in the Deployment stage. Everything else is same

Answer (score 0):

From the commentary, it sounds like the environment variables are set in the toolchain, but the Cloud Foundry application is failing because it doesn't have those same environment variables. Variables set in the toolchain are not copied over to a Cloud Foundry app by running the `push` command alone. You'll still need to run the `bx app env-set APP_NAME ENV_VAR_NAME ENV_VAR_VALUE` command similar to what's being done [here](https://github.com/open-toolchain/cf-ceg-toolchain/blob/1353aba556ddca99ad78dd6ae4305db09f20319c/.bluemix/pipeline.yml#L86) in the official toolchain samples. Notice that the sample script does a `push --no-start`, then it sets the envvars, and then it starts the app. Also use the `bx` command as the current version of the IBM Cloud CLI on toolchains is back leveled.